# CRC16-ITU proof

Tags: checksum, crc, crc16

guys. I am using CRC16-ITU check in order to compare some data, but it is not match when I compared CRC16-ITU and packet data with CRC16 from device.

Here is CRC16-ITU table.

> u16 crctab16[256] = { 0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624,
>       0x57ad,    0x6536, 0x74bf, 0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c,
>       0xdbe5,    0xe97e, 0xf8f7, 0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5,
>       0x472c,    0x75b7, 0x643e, 0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed,
>       0xcb64,    0xf9ff, 0xe876, 0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726,
>       0x76af,    0x4434, 0x55bd, 0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e,
>       0xfae7,    0xc87c, 0xd9f5, 0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7,
>       0x662e,    0x54b5, 0x453c, 0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef,
>       0xea66,    0xd8fd, 0xc974, 0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420,
>       0x15a9,    0x2732, 0x36bb, 0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868,
>       0x99e1,    0xab7a, 0xbaf3, 0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1,
>       0x0528,    0x37b3, 0x263a, 0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9,
>       0x8960,    0xbbfb, 0xaa72, 0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522,
>       0x34ab,    0x0630, 0x17b9, 0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a,
>       0xb8e3,    0x8a78, 0x9bf1, 0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3,
>       0x242a,    0x16b1, 0x0738, 0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb,
>       0xa862,    0x9af9, 0x8b70, 0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c,
>       0xd3a5,    0xe13e, 0xf0b7, 0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64,
>       0x5fed,    0x6d76, 0x7cff, 0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad,
>       0xc324,    0xf1bf, 0xe036, 0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5,
>       0x4f6c,    0x7df7, 0x6c7e, 0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e,
>       0xf2a7,    0xc03c, 0xd1b5, 0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66,
>       0x7eef,    0x4c74, 0x5dfd, 0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af,
>       0xe226,    0xd0bd, 0xc134, 0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7,
>       0x6e6e,    0x5cf5, 0x4d7c, 0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028,
>       0x91a1,    0xa33a, 0xb2b3, 0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60,
>       0x1de9,    0x2f72, 0x3efb, 0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9,
>       0x8120,    0xb3bb, 0xa232, 0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1,
>       0x0d68,    0x3ff3, 0x2e7a, 0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a,
>       0xb0a3,    0x8238, 0x93b1, 0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62,
>       0x3ceb,    0x0e70, 0x1ff9, 0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab,
>       0xa022,    0x92b9, 0x8330, 0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3,
>       0x2c6a,    0x1ef1, 0x0f78 };

========================================================================

And I used this code in order to make crc

```
u16 fcs16(u16 fcs, unsigned char *cp, int len)
{
    while(len--)
        fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *cp++) & 0xff];

    return(fcs);
}
```

Here is example of packet data from device

7e 01 11 **97 17** 7e

97 17 means CRC16 as little endian method.

when I use CRC16-ITU code in my project, I got this "4edf"

I, totally, don't understand why there is mismatching between those data.

If you have any idea, please comment for me

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CRC 0x4edf corresponds to the CRC-16/X-25 algorithm (using the 
notation from http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/)
over the byte sequence `7e 01 11`. If you compute the CRC over `01 11` you
should get 0x1797 as a 16-bit value (or `97 17` as two bytes).

Comment: I realized that I misunderstood where is start bit. when I start crc at 01 11, I got a exact data. The reason why I got wrong crc was just include 0x7e. thx your help.