# How do I implement a CRC16 with a custom polynomial in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, checksum, crc, crc16

### Background

I need to implement a CRC16 with a custom polynomial in Javascript.

### Research

After searching several NPM modules and this SO question ( as well as all the links the comments suggest ):

- [Javascript CRC16 sample code or implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795958/javascript-crc16-sample-code-or-implementation)
- https://github.com/donvercety/node-crc16

I am still not any closer to my goal.

### Problem

My problem is that even though I have the code, I can't  understand how to re-use a given CRC16 solution because I don't know where to find the polynomial definition in the code. With all the shifts and whatnot it's just too cryptic for me.

### Question

How can I have a CRC16 function with a custom polynomial ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example linked has a table *derived* from the CRC polynomial. You can certainly find [code that generates the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395142/crc16-itu-proof), given the polynomial. You can find [code that computes any CRC, and code that generates CRC code](https://github.com/madler/crcany), including the table, given the definition of the CRC (polynomial, bit-ordering, initial value, final xor value).